# Convert Python array('B') to array('H') - always little-endian?

Tags: python, arrays, endianness

I have a Python `array('B')` (containing some data read from a file), which I would like to convert to an `array('H')`. I am currently using code similar to the following:

```
a = array.array('B', f.read())
b = a[16:32]
c = array.array('H', b.tostring())
```

Unfortunately the conversion in the third line uses the native byte order, so will give different results on different machines.

Is there any way to make the conversion always little-endian, irrespective of the native byte order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`array.array` is only useful for internal calculations, because it always uses the native byte order. There is a method `byteswap` to change the order. Therefore you have to check `sys.byteorder` to determine the system byteorder, and swap accordingly.

To have better control of ordering use `struct`:

```
data = f.read()
c = struct.unpack_from('<8H', data, 16)
```